# SSH command varaible not being seen

Tags: linux, ssh, python

I am trying to pass a variable using a remote SSH command connection.  I want to rename the data file with the station variable. The SSH command is being run on a Windows PC to a Ubuntu PC. When the script is run from Python on the Windows PC it makes the connection but won’t rename the file. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

```python
import paramiko
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname="192.168.1.xx",username="xx",password="xxxx")
station = "NAA"
stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_client.exec_command(
    "mv /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/station.data \
    /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/$station.dat")
```

Comment: do you want use `station = "NAA"` in place of `$station`?

Answer (score 3):

`station` is variable in Python, not in shell - and you need Python functions, not shell `$`

string-formatting (`"{}".format(station)`)

```python
cmd = "mv /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/station.data \
    /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/{}.dat".format(station)

print("CMD:", cmd)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
```

or f-string (`f"{station}"`)

```python
cmd = f"mv /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/station.data \
    /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/{station}.dat"

print("CMD:", cmd)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
```

or old method with `%` and `%s`  (`"%s" % station`)

```python
cmd = "mv /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/station.data \
    /home/pi/vlfrx-tools/data/%s.dat" % station

print("CMD:", cmd)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
```

---

See more on page [PyFormat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

---

**EDIT:**

It is not tested but probably you could use `$station` if you set shell variable using `EXPORT` - but it still need to use Python to format string.

```
cmd = "EXPORT station={} ; mv ... .../$station.dat".format(station)
```

I'm not sure but this shell variable can be temporary and you may n need to set it in every `exec_command()` which need it.